# Using QGraphicsScene subclass with ui?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have implemented signals for mousePressEvent() in a QGraphicsScene subclass, but I can't figure out how to *use* the class in a UI. I can add a QGraphicsView widget to my UI, but how do I then access the *scene*?

```
GraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
// Add pixmap, etc
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
// Here's where I'm stuck
connect(ui->whereIsTheScene?, SIGNAL(clicked(QPoint)), this, SLOT(someSlot(QPoint));
```

EDIT: This is compiling, but the mouse press event is being ignored. I think this is a separate issue so I've posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549632/qgraphicsscene-subclass-is-ignoring-mouse-press-events)

Comment: I think you meant `...setScene(scene)` instead of ´...setScene(scn)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example: use the `scene` pointer you already have:

```
connect(scene, SIGNAL(clicked(QPoint)), this, SLOT(someSlot(QPoint));
```

Alternatively, if you don't have the pointer laying around anymore, use [this function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html#scene):

```
connect(ui->graphicsView->scene(), SIGNAL(clicked(QPoint)), this, SLOT(someSlot(QPoint));
```

(untested, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work)