# QGraphicsScene subclass is ignoring mouse press events

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have a UI and a QGraphicsScene subclass GraphicsScene that implements mousePressEvent(), however mouse clicks are being ignored.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
scene = new GraphicsScene(this);
scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(someImage));
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
connect(scene, SIGNAL(clicked(QPoint)), this, SLOT(someSlot(QPoint)));
```

GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent() is not called, and so does not emit signal clicked(). Is there something else I need to set to enable this?

UPDATE:

```
void GraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
        emit clicked(event->pos());
}
```

It's connected to a slot of the right signature.

Comment: You're going to have to show your GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent, I think.  My guess is that you've got the function signature wrong and so you're not overriding the virtual function like you think you are.

Comment: It seems that you are connecting scene's clicked signal to some slot. Should that be graphicsView's clicked signal?

Comment: Well, either should work. I'm actually debating which is better for my program. However the problem was in the signature of mousePressEvent(): the correct mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) implements the parent's virtual function, whereas mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) does not. Good times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mos was right about the function signature. The function should have been:

```
void GraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
        emit clicked(event->pos());
}
```

rather than

```
void GraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
        emit clicked(event->pos());
}
```